# Web Part - dynamically change title to folder name?

Tags: sharepoint-online

In the NewForm.aspx, I was asked to add a web part to display a library (to make it easier to upload related files).  Anyway, is there a way to dynamically change the web part title based on the folder that is current opened?

Or, is there a way to dynamically open the appropriate YEAR folder based on the item's Meeting Date year?  I probably have to create a calculated column to get the year and connect it to the web part but I can't figure out which column to use as the ***Consumer Field Name***

[image]
[image]

Comment: You will have to do it using client scripting.